# InstallShield minor update - remove previous version

Tags: installshield, visual-studio-2012

New to InstallShield, I've built a setup project and used the setup file to deploy my app.

Now I need to update the app, here is what I've done:

- Increment product version (I tried major minor and build).
- generate new upgrade code.
- build the setup project.

The installer refuses to install the app because "Another version of this product is already installed...".

How can I get InstallSheild to remove that other version?
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer: Product code should be changed instead of upgrade code and the assemblies' file version must be incremented as well.

Comment: Technically this change makes it a "Major Upgrade" (which is probably a good thing as they're a lot easier to reason about).

Comment: It shows the multiple installation in control panel.

Answer (score 3):

You should:

- Go to "Organize your setup -> Upgrade paths"
- Right-click on Upgrade Paths (listed on the left) and then "New Upgrade path"
- Now you must select the OLD installation pack, specify details on your own (:
- Just in this case, you can increase version on projects (BOTH! In general information on setup, and in Configuration/publish on application)
- After increasing, create e new Product Code on General Information (to setup) and build! (:

Hope it helps someone (: